# Why it is not possible to even ping laravel homestead VM?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am working on a mac, using vagrant & virtualbox.
Yesterday everything was working fine. But today after i run `homestead up`, i can ssh into vm, but i am not able to ping it (192.168.10.10).

In `ifconfig` i see the following (but i even can't ping 192.168.10.1):

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
inet 192.168.10.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

Comment: Is ping the only thing not working?

Comment: I can't open website by ip address. `homestead ssh` works well.

Comment: Open up VirtualBox and check that the IP didn't change. Then, check that nginx and hhvm are running in the box.

Comment: I see ip address `192.168.10.10`. Ps axu says that nginx is running. `ssh 192.168.10.10` does not work, only `homestead ssh`

Comment: There's not enough information here to know whether it would be normal to _expect_ to reach the guest from the host via its native IP address. The default mode for VirtualBox guests is NAT, in which case the host can't see the guest's IP at all.

Comment: At minimum, you might show us your Vagrantfile; then there might at least be the beginnings of enough information to work from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem here, I resolved with the following steps

- update your virtualbox app
- remove box from virutalbox gui, delete all files
- `homestead destroy`
- `homestead update`
- reboot mac
- `homestead up`

and everything was working again...

Comment: Marking answer as correct. In my case helped just reboot :)

Comment: Ditto - reboot fixed it. Windows 10.